# Changed QGuiApplication to QApplication resulted in unresolved errors

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, compiler-errors

The reason why I made the change is because I needed to use QtWidgets. I've been trying to build the project however I keep getting the following errors:

```
18:37:58: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:/Users/user/Desktop/build-project-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug --target all
[1/4 11.1/sec] Automatic MOC and UIC for target project
[2/3 1.4/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.obj
[3/3 2.0/sec] Linking CXX executable project.exe
FAILED: project.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/project.dir/project_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/project.dir/project_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_qml.cpp.obj -o project.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libproject.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Quick.a  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5QmlModels.a  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Qml.a  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Network.a  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Gui.a  C:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/lib/libQt5Core.a  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.obj: In function `main':
C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplication4execEv'
C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My current `main.cpp` is the following:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE", "Material");
    qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_THEME","Dark");
    qputenv("QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_MATERIAL_Primary","BlueGrey");
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));



    return app.exec();
}
```

And including the Qt files through Cmake was done using the following:

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(project
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick)
```

I am really not sure what the problem is so any help is appreciated

Comment: The cmd.exe line that you show above does not link libQt5Widgets.a to your application.

Comment: TYPO: change to `QtWidgets` and `find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick Widgets REQUIRED)`. Also show target_link_libraries.

Comment: @JarMan I have added it in the recent edit

Comment: @eyllanesc I have done the changes you have specified but still doesnt compile, I have added the target link libraries in the recent edit

Comment: change to `target_link_libraries(project
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't linking the Widgets library.

```
target_link_libraries(project
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
```